# paging for dynamically created gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hi I'm creating gridviews dynamically in `Page_Init` as per the received tables from the database as below , if I receive 4 tables then 4 gridviews will be generated

```
GridView gd = new GridView();
      gd.ID = "gdd" + i;
      gd.AllowPaging = true;
      gd.PageSize = 10;
      gd.PageIndexChanging += new GridViewPageEventHandler(GridView_PageIndexChanging);
```

and my question is to how to do paging for it , any help would be appreciated
and how to retain the  values when postback

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
protected void GridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    gvCustomers.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    PopulateCustomers();
}
```

For more information use [Gridview paging example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/gridview-paging-sample-in-Asp-Net/)

Comment: its dynamic created gridview and my doubt is how to retain it in postback